# Header not flush with top of webpage.

Tags: html, css

```
.header {
  height: 115px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #33CC66;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0cm;
  padding:0cm;
}
.headertext {
  font-size: 250%;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.outerdiv{
  padding:0cm;
  margin:0cm;
}
```

HTML

```
 <div className="outerdiv">
    <div className="header">
      <p className="headertext">
        Add New Habit
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div className="pics">
      {this.renderHabits().map((habitObject)=>{
        return <img src={habitObject.imageLink} height="460" width="490"/>
     })}
   </div>
 </div>
```

So I've tried playing with the padding and margin even making them negative but the header still has space between it and the top.  Thoughts?

Comment: maybe it's because of <p> but not so sure, if you can post here working code it will be better for us to understand

Comment: Wow that was it.  What was it about <p> that made it not flush with the top?  Feel free to post your answer so I can mark it as correct and upvote you.

Comment: The `p` tag is indeed part of the issue. There are webkit specific style rules being applied to it, -webkit-margin rules to be specific. The body also has a margin of 8px applied by the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's because of `<p>` but not so sure, if you can post here working code it will be better for us to understand.

`<p>` tag have a default margin that's why.

Answer (score 0):

try reseting body margin/padding to zero